# Today-Extension call specific ViewController in App

Tags: xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension

In my today-extension I use the following code to launch my app:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"hdb://"];

[[self extensionContext] openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
```

Is it possible to call a specific ViewController to be displayed after launching the app? In my app all ViewControllers are called with their segues like:

```
[self.mainSlideMenu.leftMenu performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewsPhoneSegue" sender:self];
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is actually your concern, but if your main question is how to tell the host app which controller to open (i.e., which segue to perform), you could encode that into your URL, e.g., `hdb://news` and `hdb://settings`. In the app, you'd `if-else` on `[url.host isEqualToString:@"news"]` to find the correct path within `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` in your app delegate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that tip. Had problems with url.host but this brought me to another idea.

Comment: Have you resolved your questions regarding `url.host`? Let me know if not. Of course you can also use url paths and queries to specify screens and data to show in your app. It's quite similar to designing a web service API, where your app is the server and the extension is the (web) client.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by writing in the today-extension a Int in the UserDefaults which I get now from my downloaded xml-file and in my first VC of the app I check the value by "case". So case 0 the app launches as required by the settings, case 1 the app launches with the News, case 2 with other view and so on. In each case I added to reset the Int to 0 otherwise when launching the app by the icon my settings are ignored because the value is stored from the last time the extension was used.

The code in the today-extension before the openURL is called:

```
NSString *ZwischenZiel = [[self.todayParser.todayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] View];

NSInteger Ziel = [ZwischenZiel integerValue];

NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.company.HdB"];

[sharedDefaults setInteger:Ziel forKey:@"ViewValue"];

[sharedDefaults synchronize];
```

and in the first viewController in the app:

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.company.HdB"];

NSInteger Wert = [sharedDefaults integerForKey:@"ViewValue"];

switch (Wert) {
    case 0:
        //if-else for passing the right segue respecting settings


    if ([manualStartSeite isEqual:@"lalala"]) {

        [self.mainSlideMenu.leftMenu performSegueWithIdentifier:@"lalalaPhoneSegue" sender:self];

    } else {


    }

    break;

case 1:
    //News
    [self.mainSlideMenu.leftMenu performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewsPhoneSegue" sender:self];

    [sharedDefaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"ViewValue"];

    [sharedDefaults synchronize];

    break;

case 2:
```

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand what you are asking, you can create a view controller at the very begging of your app and in its viewwillappear you can call perform segue with identifier method to call your specific view controller. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. That I've done already to launch with selected view chosen in the settings. So this "way" is used. Do you have a second option?

Comment: `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    if(condition to select which view will be displayed){
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourCustomViewName"] animated:NO];
     }else if(cnd){
      //same push method with different view ...
    }else...
}`
**This should work if you do it right in your first view controller. Do not forget to put a navigation view controller at the top.I am currently using this method** Yet I can answer further questions.